# Implementar anúncios intersticial no App

Tags: java, android, admob

Alguém pode me explicar em um tutorial resumido de como implementar, anúncios intersticial da Admob em meu app que é um navegador simples.

O problema é que fica dando classes errada, como não tenho experiência em java, não consigo implementar corretamente. Preciso de ajuda.

> Estou tentando implementar, a partir desse exemplo: [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/interstitial)

Meu código:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

if (isOnline()) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Carregando", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://xxxx.xx");//Link por defeito
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_VIEW){
        uri = intent.getData();
    }
    mWebView.loadUrl(uri.toString());
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new LinkWebViewClient());
    mWebView.requestFocusFromTouch();
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    }
else
[...]
}
private class LinkWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
{
    if(isOnline()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        webview.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sem conexão", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.conexaofail);
        return false;
    }
}
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {

if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack())
{
    if (isOnline()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.conexaofail);
        return false;
    }
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
```

Alguém pode me ajudar? Peço que tenha um pouco de paciência comigo, pois sou iniciante e eu quero aprender.

Comment: Seu código sugere que sua aplicação roda em um webview, não tem nenhum código do anuncio ai. Você deu uma olhada no git do firebase, esta bem simples a implementação do anúncio interstical. [https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/blob/master/admob/InterstitialExample/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/example/interstitialexample/MyActivity.java]

Comment: Deu erro 404 no seu link!

Comment: [Link Git][1]


  [1]: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/admob/InterstitialExample

Comment: Conseguir! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Ótimo, feliz em ter ajudado.